# PhpStorm 2017.2 | Navigating by file name [Ctrl+Shift+N] doesn't work

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

Since last update, PhpStorm's file navigation box doesn't work when I use the command `Ctrl+Shift+N`. It opens and closes quickly.

Any ideas? I don't want to go back to the previous version.

Comment: Are you using Linux OS?

Comment: I have it under "Navigate" -> "File". On my machine, its Cmd+Shift+R

Comment: @LazyOne Yes, Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 64-bit

Comment: See the links/workarounds in duplicate answer. If anything -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173000#comment=27-2335351

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you, it works :)

Comment: @adriaroca Don't forget to upvote that answer as well. It works like "yes, I conform it works" kind of comment -- helpful for other users in similar situation.